# Dart / rxdart / Bloc: receive event item with original type when listening to a BehaviorSubject's stream

Tags: stream, dart, flutter, rxdart

Consider this code (don't mind the useless `listen` method, it's just to show the use case):

```
class Bloc {
  final BehaviorSubject notifPrompt =
    BehaviorSubject<NotifPromptModel>()..add(NotifPromptModel(answered: false));

  void listen() {
    notifPrompt.stream.listen(
      (data) => print(data.answered)
    );
  }

  void dispose() {
    notifPrompt.close();
  }
}

class NotifPromptModel {
  final bool answered;

  NotifPromptModel({this.answered});
}
```

Now I know that this will work, but is there a way to get the `generic type`, `NotifPromptModel` in this case, that I pass to the `BehaviorSubject` (`StreamController` that sends last `event` on every new `listen`) with the `data` parameter? This would allow me to have convenient code suggestions when I'm passing an `object` containing the `model` information as `fields` to the `BehaviorSubject`, like in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Should have spent some minutes more thinking. The problem was that I instantiated the `BehaviorSubject` `object` with the `type`, but didn't `declare` the `variable` with it.